# Trigger to check a condition

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a trigger on table t1. If any bad record is inserted in t1, I need to insert in table 2.  But it is mutating. Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

I am using oracle 12c.

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER test_air_tr
    AFTER INSERT
    ON t1 
    FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

  v_count NUMBER;

BEGIN
--condition to check bad record. 
SELECT COUNT(*)  INTO v_count  FROM t1
     WHERE  col1=:new.col2;

IF (v_count>0) THEN 
    INSERT INTO t2
        (
          col1 ,           
          col2  )        
        VALUES
        (
         :new.col1 ,           
         :new.col2
        ) ;
END IF;

 EXCEPTION
       WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX  THEN
        UPDATE t2
            SET col2               =:new.col2

            WHERE col1       =:new.col1;
END;
```

Comment: In the trigger you can change `AFTER INSERT` to before insert if thats suits you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens as the table on which the trigger is defined is also queried in the trigger.  One solution of the issue is to use pragma autonomous transaction and move the logic of the trigger in a procedure that uses this pragma and call this procedure in the trigger.

In my system, I was able to reproduce the error and also verify that the below solution works:

```
SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               NUMBER
 COL2                                               NUMBER

(Same structure for t2 table).

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_bad_data (p_col1 NUMBER, p_col2 NUMBER)
IS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   v_cnt   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO v_cnt
     FROM t1
    WHERE col1 = p_col2;

   IF (v_cnt > 0)
   THEN
      INSERT INTO t2 (col1, col2)
           VALUES (P_col1, P_col2);
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
   THEN
      UPDATE t2
         SET col2 = p_col2
       WHERE col1 = p_col1;
END;
/

--

create or replace 
TRIGGER test_air_tr
    AFTER INSERT
    ON t1 
    FOR EACH ROW
begin

 check_bad_data(:new.col1,:new.col2);

end;

SQL> insert into t1 values(1,2);

1 row created. 

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Note that this is only one possible solution and there could be other ways too.  I saw this URL which helped me to get this solution:
https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/mutating-table-errorin-oraclewhyithappensand-what-you-can-doabout-it.html

--from my system:

```
SQL> delete from t1;

9 rows deleted.

SQL> delete from t2;

3 rows deleted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into t1 values(1,2);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          2

SQL> select * from t2;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into t1 values (3,4);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t2;

no rows selected

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t2;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into t1 values (4,1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         3          4
         4          1
         1          2

SQL> select * from t2;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         4          1
```

Comment: Thank you dbusern for the reply! It resolved my mutating trigger issue. However I need the data to be inserted in t2 only when v_cnt > 0. But here what happens is as soon as I insert a new record ( which is not a bad record ) - since it is inserted already in table 1, it considers inside the procedure that it is a bad record.     Eg: insert into t1 values(1,2);   in the procedure it satisfies the v_count condition, bad record is inserted.

Comment: Hi Arc, thank you for the reply. I don't know the second part of how to work out the solution for the second issue. I did check in my system that if I insert a new record like (7,8) it does not go to the second table. But let me  be honest and say that may be there is something more that I don't know.  If it is ok can you please raise a new question for it. Or please make this question back as unsolved and someone else can respond with better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Arc, I added some more output from my system in the original answer. It seems to be working fine in my system. Please double check if there is really an issue and review the output that I have placed in the original answer - it does  Not seem to add good records to the second table.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you very much dbusern for checking this for me .Sorry, The fault was at my end and I had some other trigger enabled. I disabled it now and all good! Thanks once again!